# How to jump to table to table for 2 times to get the field I want, using outer join

Tags: c#, sql, outer-join

I have three tables, which is prescription, appointment and payment. Prescription have relationship with appointment and appointment have relationship with payment. Currently I only manage to jump from prescription table to appointment table and get the aDate field and display it in the dategridview. Now I need to jump from prescription table to appointment table and then to payment table to get the amount field. How do i write it?

MY DATEGRIDVIEW
[image]

MY TABLES
[image]

```
private void prescription_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPrescriptionRecords();
        }

        private void LoadPrescriptionRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command

            //string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres";
            string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment as app on pres.appointmentid = app.appointmentid";

            myConnect.Open();

            PrescriptionAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //readMEDICATION.Close();
            myConnect.Close();      

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PrescriptionAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Prescription.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            PrescriptionAdapter.Fill(Prescription);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Prescription.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdPrescription.DataSource = Prescription;         
        }
```

Comment: This was an easy one, thats why 3 of us are hitting for the fence. You need to so a little more learning in SQL. I would suggest finding a SQL tool like SSMS to run your queries through before adding the complexities of C# and all the connection classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `strCommandText` just do one more join i.e. join appointment to payment.

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate, p.amount FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres ";
strCommandText += "LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment as app on pres.appointmentid = app.appointmentid ";
strCommandText += "LEFT OUTER JOIN payment p on app.appointmentid = p.appointmentid ";
```

Comment: Thanks, u miss out  p.amount on the first line. @peter.petrov

Comment: Thanks. erm, by using outer join, that means I can't do a update function on the datagridview right? @peter.petrov

Comment: @Jordjmax When it is `T1 INNER JOIN T2` and there's no corresponding row in T2, you will not get a row at all in the returned result set.

Comment: @Jordjmax `T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2` means that there will be a row in the returned result set even if there's no corresponding row in T2; in that case if your select clause includes some columns from T2, you will get NULL values for them in the returned row.

Comment: So...  u mean INNER join allows updating of datagridview, and outer join doesn't is it? and your T means column? @peter.petrov

Comment: Because if i do the update function button, it will give me (Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.) @peter.petrov

Comment: I don't think INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN matters for this. Check here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a8f3565-ca1d-4042-b18d-e46cc8e26e3f/dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables Also consider posting another question specifically for this (unless that question already exists on SO).

Comment: Google your most recent error. You will find lots of information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just join it with `payment` table as you did with the other one.

```
SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate,pay.Amount FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres
 LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment as app on pres.appointmentid = app.appointmentid
 Left outer join Payment as pay on app.appointmentid = pay.appointmentid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate, P.Amount 
 FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment as app on pres.appointmentid = app.appointmentid 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment as P on P.appointmentid = pres.appointmentid";
```

EDIT:This was an easy one, that's why 3 of us are hitting for the fence. You need to so a little more learning in SQL. I would suggest finding a SQL tool like SSMS to run your queries through before adding the complexities of C# and all the connection classes.
[SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx)